# Powershell create table from key value pairs with key as column heading

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

I have multiple rows of data in a powershell script that look like:

```
SSAS=PerformanceAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=LAP123;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=PerformanceDataMart:
SSAS=EnvironmentalAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=LAP123;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=EnvironmentalDataMart:
```

I'm currently using:

```
ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ";" -PropertyNames Server, Provider, Source, Security, Catalog.
```

Which gives me:

```
Server                                                  Provider            Source                   Security                              
------                                                  --------            ------                   --------                              
SSAS=EnvironmentalAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1 Data Source=LAP123  Integrated Security=SSPI Initial Catalog=EnvironmentalDataMart:
SSAS=PerformanceAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1   Data Source=DEV-EDW Integrated Security=SSPI Initial Catalog=PerformanceDataMart:
```

I'd like to create a table, with the key as the column headings, or even to be able to strip the key out of the table data.

```
+------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
|            SSAS              |  Provider   | Data Source |    Security     |    Catalog            |
+------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| EnvironmentalAnalysisService | SQLNCLI11.1 | LAP123      | Integrated SSPI | EnvironmentalDataMart |
| PerformanceAnalysisService   | SQLNCLI11.1 | LAP123      | Integrated SSPI | PerformanceDataMart   |
+------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

But is there a way to identify the key/column names and the strip them out dynamically?

The end result will be used by SQL. So either returning the data as seperate columns, or comma seperated would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConverTo-Csv` should be able to do that, simply pipe the output of `ConvertFrom-String` to it.

```
> $in = "SSAS=PerformanceAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=LAP123;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=PerformanceDataMart:","SSAS=EnvironmentalAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=LAP123;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=EnvironmentalDataMart:"
> $in | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ";" -PropertyNames Server, Provider, Source, Security, Catalog | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
"Server";"Provider";"Source";"Security"
"SSAS=PerformanceAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1";"Data Source=LAP123";"Integrated Security=SSPI";"Initial Catalog=PerformanceDataMart:"
"SSAS=EnvironmentalAnalysisService, Provider=SQLNCLI11.1";"Data Source=LAP123";"Integrated Security=SSPI";"Initial Catalog=EnvironmentalDataMart:"
```

You can also replace `ConverTo-Csv` with `Export-Csv` if you want to store the content to a CSV file, or you can pipe the output of `ConvertTo-Csv` to `Out-File`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and gvie that a go tommorrow.